# CryptoJS saying Crytpo.js file not found error

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

So I am trying to use the CryptoJS and I have been trying to use it two ways. One without require and the other with require and I am running into issues with both ways. When I try to use it without require, I get an error saying file not found
[image]

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/bower_components/cryptojs/cryptojs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES('Message');
    console.log(encrypted);
</script>
```

When I try to use require, and use require.js I still get an error that says 
Uncaught reference error: Require not defined
[image]

Comment: looks like your src link is wrong, src="./public" if you are trying to load something from your local.

Comment: And it needs to be said that it's not sane trying to do any kind of web-development without spinning up some sort of [webserver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) because of how strict browsers are with local files. (sorry for butting in)

Comment: karthick, I just tried that, I am still getting the same error